# Cant set title or button inside UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I inherit from `UINavigationController` now I want to set a button and my title in `ViewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"TEST"];

    [self setToolbarHidden:YES];
}
```

But i doesn't work, I think its something I miss.

Comment: do you want to set navigationItem title?

Comment: its one of my test which property I need to set when I want to set the title in my navigationbar

Comment: Then its simple self.title = @"Your Title", its done

Comment: @Sebastian-in you previous viewController is root view of  NavigationController ?

Comment: its only a viewcontroller in my custom uinavigationcontroller and I want to set the buttons in my uinavigationcontroller itself

Answer (score 1):

For set title of UINavigationBar

use

```
self.title = @"TESTING";
```

and BarButton on NavigationBar

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showActionsheet)] autorelease];
```

Comment: thats my problem that doesn't work... I can set everything great from my UiViewController inside the NavigationController but not in my NavigationController itself